# Find exceptions in jagged array of strings (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, rows

I have some data that I read into a jagged array of strings. An example of such arrays:

```
string[] row = { "John", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
```

and I will have an array to hold these rows of strings. A very long one.

What I want to do is find all the rows with the same name ("**John**"). Then compare these rows to see if they are identical. Print all of them if there are any exceptions, otherwise continue to next name.

So for example if I have 10 rows of "**John**"s, I want to check whether the attributes on all 10 of them are exactly "**Apple**", "**Orange**" and "**Banana**". And I will have thousands of names other than "**John**" that I want to do the same thing with.

Is there an efficient algorithm to do this? I will be writing it in C#.

Comment: smells like homework... if so, please add the homework tag :)

Comment: actually it's for a small utility I'm developing for my own convenience :)

Comment: It'd make a good homework assignment though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq you could do the following:

```
var rows = new string[][]
{
    new string[] {"John", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"},
    new string[] {"John", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"},
    new string[] {"John", "Apple", "Lemon", "Banana"},
    new string[] {"John", "Apple", "Orange", "Grape"},
    new string[] {"Sam", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"},
    new string[] {"Sam", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"},
};

var results = (from f in rows
              where f.Contains("Sam")
              select f).Distinct(new ArrayComparer());
```

However, this does require the creation of a custom comparer class as follows:

```
class ArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;

        var left = x.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
        var right = y.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();

        for (int index = 0; index < x.Length; index++)
        {
            if (left[index] == right[index])
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string[] obj)
    {
        int hash = 23;
        foreach (var element in obj.OrderBy(s => s))
        {
            hash = hash * 37 + element.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

The results of using John would be 3 rows and the results with Sam would be 2 rows.  If you want to ignore case you would just have to change `OrderBy(s => s)` to `OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Works pretty well...just need to make some small adjustments for my needs :) Thanks!